# There is no method named delay() in celery shared_task decorator, how to fix it?

Tags: django, celery

```
# orders/tasks.py
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .models import Order

@shared_task
def order_created(order_id):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    subject = f'Order nr.{order.id}'
    message = f'Dear {order.first_name},\n\n You have successfully placed an order. Your order ID is {order.id}.'
    mail_sent = send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@myshop.com', [order.email])
    return mail_sent

# orders/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import OrderItem
from .forms import OrderCreateForm
from cart.cart import Cart
from .tasks import order_created

def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(
                    order=order,
                    product=item['product'],
                    price=item['price'],
                    quantity=item['quantity']
                )
            cart.clear()

            order_created.delay(order.id)

            return render(request, 'orders/order/created.html', {'order': order})
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'orders/order/create.html', {'form': form})
```

i imported celery in my project , and want to create an asynchronous task,
after reading celery docs i think i do everything right , and still
delay method does not exist

Django==5.0.1
celery==5.3.6

Comment: Based on what you've posted I think you're using `@shared_task` incorrectly. It still needs to be configured, I think this SO answer would also answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233089/how-do-i-use-the-shared-task-decorator-for-class-based-tasks

Answer (score 0):

According to [Celery signatures documentation](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#signatures),

You can run your task synchronously by:

```py
order_created.s(order.id).apply()
```

or asynchronously by:

```py
order_created.s(order.id).apply_async()
```